# Optimize Query (remove subquery)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can you help me to optimize this Query ?. I need to remove the subquery because the performance is awful.

```
select LICENSE,
       (select top 1 SERVICE_KEY 
        from SERVICES 
        where SERVICES.LICENSE = VEHICLE.LICENSE
        order by DATE desc, HOUR desc)
from VEHICLE
```

The problem is that I can have two SERVICES on the same DATE and HOUR, so I haven't been able to code an equivalent SQL avoiding the subquery.

The query runs on a Legacy database where I can't modify its metadata, and it doesn't have any index at all. That's the reason to look for a solution that can avoid a correlated query.

Thank you.

Comment: Share actual execution plan.

Comment: Do you have indexes on the License columns?

Comment: Please share DDL and Indexes and table size

Comment: If you can have two services on the same data and hour how do you know which is the right one to display, are there any business rules?

Comment: The correlated query is OK,check if you have indexes on the LICENSE column in both tables

Comment: First three comments are the key to fix your problem

Comment: @SteveFord, You are right, but this is a Legacy Database with no referential integrity at all, and I shouldn't modify its metadata. In the case of two services at the same time and hour, I can return anyone of them.

Comment: @SteveFord it would be a very quick technician that could service the same vehicle twice in a single hour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can express your query using `ROW_NUMBER()` without the need for a correlated subquery.  Try the following query and see how the peformance is:

```
SELECT t.LICENSE, t.SERVICE_KEY
FROM
(
    SELECT t1.LICENSE, t1.SERVICE_KEY
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.LICENSE
                          ORDER BY t2.DATE DESC, t2.HOUR DESC) rn
    FROM VEHICLE t1
    INNER JOIN SERVICES t2
        ON t1.LICENSE = t2.LICENSE
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

The performance of this query would depend, among other things, on having indices on the join columns of your two tables.